# Separation of Logic: Search, Database, & Application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, solr, full-text-search, redis

I'm trying to decide how I want to split up my logic.

I'm placing my main business logic in Node.js/Express, and I had been using Mongo for my database. This works great, but now I need to implement a really powerful search system, as search is one of the most important features of my site. At first I was very amazed at the lack of support and integration that Mongo and Couch offered, but then I realized I was trying to get a database to do something it wasn't made for.

Now I'm looking at using Solr or ElasticSearch, but its beginning to seem that these are capable of even doing some or most of the queries that Mongo can do, as long as I index my documents correctly (and by their nature, I will be indexing pretty much every property of every document). So that said, I'm thinking maybe I should just use something dead simple, like Redis, and rely on a powerful search tool like Solr/ElasticSearch instead.

Does this seem like a wise choice? Also, why are there no Nodejs modules for Solr, Lucene, or ElasticSearch?

Comment: I also just found [RedBackJS](http://redbackjs.com) which looks like it might be the right solution for me, but again, I'm interested in the wisdom of some more experienced architects.

Comment: You mostly need only a HTTP client library (preferably one that can pool connections) and you can make a solr query class by yourself (dont forget to do URL and Solr char escaping).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB + Solr (or even better ElasticSearch) does sound like a reasonable choice for an app that has search as one of the most important features. MongoDB is not made for full text search, Solr (Lucene) is. And Solr is not meant to be a system of record (MongoDB is).

MongoDB vs Redis? Difficult to say without any requirements specified. I'd pick mongo at least for the sake of ad hoc queries. In any case, make sure you study the fantastic series of blog posts called [jepsen](https://aphyr.com/tags/jepsen) by [Kyle Kingsbury](https://twitter.com/aphyr), both [mongodb](https://aphyr.com/posts/284-call-me-maybe-mongodb) and [redis](https://aphyr.com/posts/283-call-me-maybe-redis) were covered.

Comment: MongoDB vs Redis, which way would you lean if you realized you'd need to be using id's in Mongo, and code joins, (so as to not be duplicating records and avoiding insane updates)?

Comment: @AgentZebra not sure what you mean by dup records and insane updates, guess probably trying to update multiple documents in a 'single transaction'?

Comment: Hi @milan, yes exactly.

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/ doesn't work for you? is it a sign the db model/schema should be changed? or that you need a different data model/db, maybe graph (neo4j) or relational (postgresql)?